# White screen of death codeigniter Error Reporting ON

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

There are several of these post on stack overflow but none of them have helped me yet. I am running a CodeIgniter install and I am getting a white screen of death on every function I try and run and it errors out with a white screen of death. So just so everyone knows errors are on. I have php.ini set to E_ALL, and DISPLAY_ERRORS = TRUE and I also have

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',TRUE);
```

Pasted in the index.php and the controller itself as I have read in several SO posts. Here is the issue, I have a controller called video and a function called test that var dumps and echos a bunch of stuff. So my url is Mydomain.com/index.php/video/test and I just get a white screen. I assume the routes are working because if I change it to Mydomain.com/index.php/somethingelse/somethingelse it breaks and gives me a 404. Does anyone know how I can get around this white screen of death? No errors are being shown anywhere, none of my echos are being output and none of my var dumps and its driving me insane!

Edit to show video controller

```
<?php
class Video extends MY_Controller{
    public function test(){
        echo "do something";
        var_dump("anything");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of your video controller?

Comment: Just edited to show video controller code

Comment: This is extending "MY_Controller", can we see that? This looks OK.

Comment: have you tried renaming test to index? What is on you core/MY_Controller.php if you do not have it then should be CI_Controller. You also may need to have a constructor

Comment: I found the solution! I enabled errors, restarted everything and went to index.php and it was a DB connection typo. So weird that it would not say this anywhere!